# Unrecognized name: inventory at [14:2]

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

```
with sales_history as (
  SELECT
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Date) AS YEAR 
  , EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Date) AS MONTH 
  , StoreID 
  , SUM(quantity) AS UnitsSold 
  , AVG(UnitPrice) AS UnitPriceProxy 
  , COUNT(DISTINCT salesID) AS NumTransactions 
  FROM `my-project-7869-408305.sales.sales_info`
  GROUP BY   YEAR,   MONTH, ProductId, StoreID
)
SELECT
 inventory.*
 , (SELECT AVG(UnitsSold) FROM sales_history
      WHERE inventory.ProductID=sales_history.ProductID
      AND inventory.StoreID=sales_history.StoreID) AS avg_quantity_sold_in_a_month
FROM `my-project-7869-408305.sales.inventory`
```

It says that the inventory name is unrecognized. How can I rectify this issue?
Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Hi - you are using a table alias in your SELECT statement (inventory.*) but you haven't actually aliased your table `my-project-7869-408305.sales.inventory`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to alias your table as "inventory", see:

```
with sales_history as (
  SELECT
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Date) AS YEAR 
  , EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Date) AS MONTH 
  , StoreID 
  , SUM(quantity) AS UnitsSold 
  , AVG(UnitPrice) AS UnitPriceProxy 
  , COUNT(DISTINCT salesID) AS NumTransactions 
  FROM `my-project-7869-408305.sales.sales_info`
  GROUP BY   YEAR,   MONTH, ProductId, StoreID
)
SELECT
 inventory.*
 , (SELECT AVG(UnitsSold) FROM sales_history
      WHERE inventory.ProductID=sales_history.ProductID
      AND inventory.StoreID=sales_history.StoreID) AS avg_quantity_sold_in_a_month
FROM `my-project-7869-408305.sales.inventory` inventory
```

Answer (score 0):

There are fe issues here:

1. You have not used `ProductId` in CTE so you can not use it in the Query using the CTE. (You are using it in the inner query: `inventory.ProductID=sales_history.ProductID`)
2. You have not given alias to your table `my-project-7869-408305.sales.inventory` in main query.

You can use the following query:

```
with sales_history as (
  SELECT
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Date) AS YEAR 
  , EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Date) AS MONTH 
  , StoreID 
  , SUM(quantity) AS UnitsSold 
  , AVG(UnitPrice) AS UnitPriceProxy 
  , COUNT(DISTINCT salesID) AS NumTransactions 
  , ProductId -- Added this 
  FROM `my-project-7869-408305.sales.sales_info`
  GROUP BY   YEAR,   MONTH, ProductId, StoreID
)
SELECT
 inventory.*
 , (SELECT AVG(UnitsSold) FROM sales_history
      WHERE inventory.ProductID=sales_history.ProductID
      AND inventory.StoreID=sales_history.StoreID) AS avg_quantity_sold_in_a_month
FROM `my-project-7869-408305.sales.inventory` inventory -- Added this
```